# How to set password on applications in Mac OS to prevent an administrator to start them?

Tags: network, access-control, macos

Is there any program that can set password on the app like mail or browser? I know about parent control, but I doesn't work with administrator account.

What I want is some program that blocks some apps from launching with popup password window.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, an administrator account can do anything. If you want to prevent someone from running some applications, don't give them an administrator account.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in a way that the admin account could override. OS X is based on Unix and all admins on the system have the sudo privilege (running anything as root) ergo they can do anything.

There probably is something that would make a popup password window come up, but it wouldn't be secure.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent an administrator from launching an application. What you *can* do is encrypt the data used by said application so that the administrator cannot access that data. Have a look at [Espionage](http://www.espionageapp.com/) which comes with preconfigured settings for common use cases like Mail.app, etc.

Comment: You can encrypt the data, but only if it's never going to be decrypted on that system. Otherwise the administrator can install a spying program that capture the decryption credentials the next time they are entered.